# Spotify 0.8.2.527 disables @font-face in apps

Tags: spotify

Was reading the blog post; http://www.spotify.com/uk/blog/archives/2012/02/23/spotify-now-with-gapless-playback-crossfade/

Downloaded the preview and now font face is disabled. We've tried eot, woff, ttf, svg. In the network panel, only SVG loads in, but in the preview tab and on page it renders as Times New Roman. It was working before, but now doesn't work with our current implementation or a stock font-squirrel implementation. Any ideas, it worked fine in 0.8.10.3

EDIT - SVG works, but not .woff or .ttf as before. All of them work in 0.8.10.3

Answer (score 2):

This has been temporarily disabled in the new version due to memory leaks and unexpected crashes of the client.

We'll enable it again when we upgrade to a newer version of Chromium Embedded Framework.

Comment: Hi pompa, can you confirm if the font-face feature is still disabled in version 0.8.4.124?

Comment: It's still disabled. I have no ETA on when we expect to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's not all that doesn't work.  Now, gapless playback, crossfade and even the repeat function are stuck on (the last intermittently as my playlist sometimes repeats and sometimes does not, though the repeat annunciator remains off).  The boxes for gapless and crossfade are unchecked.  If I check them, close the client, start it again, uncheck them, close the client and start it again, the boxes remain unchecked, but the ferstunkener build 572 still messes-up the transitions, truncating up to five seconds or so from the start of each cut.