# Embedding Fonts.com fonts in a Spotify App

Tags: spotify, webfonts

I am currently trying to embed fonts from Fonts.com into my Spotify app without much luck. I have already added **http://fast.fonts.com/** and **http://*.fonts.com/** into the manifest.json as allowed domains, and I have tried both the CSS and JS methods for embedding - has anyone else had better luck with embedding fonts specifically from Fonts.com?

I have also added a variety of different domains in the Fonts.com allow list to try and work it out, including; "*", "127.0.0.1", "localhost", "sp://spotify:app:appname", "sp://spotify-app-appname"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an open issue. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422079/1553481) from [pompa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126289/pompa), who claims to be related to Spotify, this as of September 2012 was still an open issue with no ETA. According to various other answers on StackOverflow and elsewhere, nobody got that to work.

This was [apparently disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762182/1553481) because of an incompatiblity/stability issue in [Chromium Embedded Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) which is used for the Spotify desktop app. Pompa stated that this was going to be replaced by CEF3 eventually, but never indicated when this was going to happen.

Comment: Good fun. I will need to embed locally then. :-)